# Запрос значение из списка через requests в youtube api

Tags: python, requests, youtube-api

Когда я делаю запрос по адресу `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&key=КлючАпи` и пытаюсь получить значение подписчиков в данный момент с помощью `r.json().get("items").get("statistics").get("subscriberCount")` - то у меня появляется ошибка `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`. Не могу представить как можно запрашивать информацию у нужно мне списка, подскажите как можно запросить `subscriberCount` с помощью `requests`

Comment: `.get` это метод словаря, а не списка :) И вместо `.get` можно использовать квадратные скобки: `x['statistics']["subscriberCount"]`

Comment: @gil9red, под `x` что будет? Сейчас сделал так: `x = r.get("items")`, но не сработало, подскажите ;з

Comment: Взял кусочек кода из вашего ответа: `[x['statistics']["subscriberCount"] for x in r["items"]]`. Метод `.get` нужно использовать если вторым параметром указывать значение по умолчанию, т.е. значение, что вернет если запрашиваемого ключа нет в словаре.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог запросить кол-во подписчиков и другую информацию из `statistics` с помощью:
 `[x.get('statistics').get("subscriberCount") for x in r.get("items")]`